# Place "Power Off" as last option in the system menu?

Tags: gnome, shutdown, menu, button, design

I have been using Ubuntu 21.10 for about slightly more than a month now and there is a design choice that irritates me.

The "Log Out" button is placed below the "Power Off" button in the system menu.  You can see the image link below.

[image: Image depicting menu with "Lock", followed by a seperator, then "Restart", "Power Off", and "Log Out"]

It irritates me as I am used to clicking the last option in the menu, like Mac OS. Is there a way to put the "Power Off" button below the "Log Out?"

I have installed a few different Extensions to try and fix this.

"Bring Out SubMenu of Power Off/Logout Button"
[image]
As you can see there is no option for me to reaarange. :/

"Top Bar Organiser"

A few others, but just haven't been able to put the Power Off Button below the Logout Button. Does anyone have a clue on how to reorder the options?

Also, I chanced on a few menu designs that look good like the link below.

[image: A different menu design]

I believe this was Gnome3 in 18.04? I much prefer the round buttons. I will be okay switching to this look too.

Thanks in advance for helping me!

Comment: Hi kelv.. it is possible to tweak as you wish by editing bringoutsubmenu extension. Do you still keep this extension?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7uA8.jpg

Comment: @UnKNOWn better to post answers as an answer here.

Comment: @UnKNOWn Could you show me how? The page that appears seems like it couldn't

Comment: I edited the question to show my bringoutsubmenu extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can tweak the order by editing the extensions `extension.js` file.

Open the extensions `extension.js` file with below command

```
gedit $HOME/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/BringOutSubmenuOfPowerOffLogoutButton@pratap.fastmail.fm/extension.js
```

Reorder the menu as you wish from `_nextAction()` funtion, for example

```
_nextAction() {
let boolean;
    // Separator1
boolean = this.gsettings.get_boolean('remove-separator-1');
if (!boolean) { SystemMenu.addMenuItem(separator1); };
    // Suspend
boolean = this.gsettings.get_boolean('remove-suspend-button');
if (!boolean) { SystemMenu.addMenuItem(suspend); };
    // Switch User
SystemMenu.addMenuItem(switchUser);
let bindFlags = GObject.BindingFlags.DEFAULT | GObject.BindingFlags.SYNC_CREATE;
DefaultActions.bind_property('can-switch-user', switchUser, 'visible', bindFlags);
    // Separator2
boolean = this.gsettings.get_boolean('remove-separator-2');
if (!boolean) { SystemMenu.addMenuItem(separator2); };
    // Logout
boolean = this.gsettings.get_boolean('remove-logout-button');
if (!boolean) { SystemMenu.addMenuItem(logout); };
    //Restart
boolean = this.gsettings.get_boolean('remove-restart-button');  
if (!boolean) { SystemMenu.addMenuItem(restart); };
    // Power
boolean = this.gsettings.get_boolean('remove-power-button');
if (!boolean) { SystemMenu.addMenuItem(power); };
}
```

[image]

Comment: It worked wonderfully! Thank you so much @UnKNOWn

Answer (score 2):

With the new Update to the extension, the code has changed a bit, so to do this.

[image]

Turn on the  option

Then, using the command from @UnKNOWn answer

Open the extensions extension.js file with below command

```
gedit $HOME/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/BringOutSubmenuOfPowerOffLogoutButton@pratap.fastmail.fm/extension.js
```

Reorder the menu as you wish from _createMenu() funtion, for example

```
_createMenu() {
    let bindFlags = GObject.BindingFlags.DEFAULT | GObject.BindingFlags.SYNC_CREATE;
    let forceLockDown = this._settings.get_boolean('force-lock-down');
    let boolean;
    
    // Separator1
    
    boolean = this._settings.get_boolean('remove-separator-1');
    if (!boolean) { SystemMenu.addMenuItem(separator1); };
    
    // Suspend
    

    suspend = new PopupMenu.PopupImageMenuItem(_('Suspend'), 'media-playback-pause-symbolic');
    suspend.connect('activate', () => {
                        DefaultActions.activateSuspend();
                });
    
    if(!forceLockDown) {
            SystemMenu.addMenuItem(suspend);
            DefaultActions.bind_property('can-suspend', suspend, 'visible', bindFlags);
            } else {
                boolean = this._settings.get_boolean('remove-suspend-button');
                if (!boolean) {
                SystemMenu.addMenuItem(suspend);
                // DefaultActions.bind_property('can-suspend', suspend, 'visible', bindFlags);
                        }
                }
                
    
                
    // Restart

    restart = new PopupMenu.PopupImageMenuItem(_('Restart…'), 'system-reboot-symbolic');
    restart.connect('activate', () => {
                            SHELL_MAJOR_VERSION >= 40 ? DefaultActions.activateRestart() : SessionManager.RebootRemote();
                    });
    
    if(!forceLockDown) {
            SystemMenu.addMenuItem(restart);
            SHELL_MAJOR_VERSION >= 40 ? DefaultActions.bind_property('can-restart', restart, 'visible', bindFlags) :
                            DefaultActions.bind_property('can-power-off', restart, 'visible', bindFlags);
            } else {
                boolean = this._settings.get_boolean('remove-restart-button');
                if (!boolean) {
                SystemMenu.addMenuItem(restart);
                // SHELL_MAJOR_VERSION >= 40 ? DefaultActions.bind_property('can-restart', this._restartButton, 'visible', bindFlags) :
                                // DefaultActions.bind_property('can-power-off', this._restartButton, 'visible', bindFlags);
                        }
                }
                
    // Logout

    logout = new PopupMenu.PopupImageMenuItem(_('Log Out'), 'system-log-out-symbolic');
    logout.connect('activate', () => { DefaultActions.activateLogout(); });
    
    if(!forceLockDown) {
            SystemMenu.addMenuItem(logout);
            DefaultActions.bind_property('can-logout', logout, 'visible', bindFlags);
            } else {
                boolean = this._settings.get_boolean('remove-logout-button');
                if (!boolean) {
                SystemMenu.addMenuItem(logout);
                // DefaultActions.bind_property('can-logout', logout, 'visible', bindFlags);
                        }
                }
                
    
    // Separator2
    
    boolean = this._settings.get_boolean('remove-separator-2');
    if (!boolean) { SystemMenu.addMenuItem(separator2); };
    
    
                
    // Power

    power = new PopupMenu.PopupImageMenuItem(_('Power Off…'), 'system-shutdown-symbolic');
    power.connect('activate', () => { DefaultActions.activatePowerOff(); });
    
    if(!forceLockDown) {
            SystemMenu.addMenuItem(power);
            DefaultActions.bind_property('can-power-off', power, 'visible', bindFlags);
            } else {
                boolean = this._settings.get_boolean('remove-power-button');
                if (!boolean) {
                SystemMenu.addMenuItem(power);
                // DefaultActions.bind_property('can-suspend', suspend, 'visible', bindFlags);
                        }
                }
                
                
    // Switch User

    switchUser = new PopupMenu.PopupImageMenuItem(_('Switch User…'), 'system-switch-user-symbolic');
    SystemMenu.addMenuItem(switchUser)
    switchUser.connect('activate', () => { DefaultActions.activatSwitchUser(); });
    DefaultActions.bind_property('can-switch-user', switchUser, 'visible', bindFlags);
    
    DefaultActions.forceUpdate();   

    }
```

You should get a menu that looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Nice catch @kelv. have you checked without turning on the "Force Lockdown Keys" if the order is changed? https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4693/rounded-system-menu-buttons/ Have a look on this for Round Buttons